# Difference between Expert at & expert in

Tags: prepositions

> I am expert in speaking English

Or

> I am expert at speaking English

Which one is correct?

Comment: Hello, welcome to English Language and Usage SE. I advise taking the site [tour] to get a feel for how the site works. The goal of this site is to provide detailed answers to questions about English. Because of this, questions are expected to provide detail and context to make it easier for other users to write good answers. Please [edit] your question to say what you've found so far.

Comment: Closely related: [Is it "expert in" or "expert on"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111469/is-it-expert-in-or-expert-on)

Comment: I'd say that '[he is etc] expert in' is usually followed by a field (expert in banking), while '[ I am etc] expert at' is usually followed by a less general practice (expert at knitting). Here, I'd say 'speaking English' is borderline, allowing either.

Comment: Your question leads one to wonder where exactly the speaker's expertise lies in this instance, whether in their ability to speak the language (as opposed to writing it) or in their knowledge of English or both.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct but in different contexts

I am an expert in computing

I work with computers I am the expert at my company.

Comment: These do not use 'expert' the way OP indicates (as an adjective).

Comment: Edwin's right, they don't.

Speaking either very strictly or colloquially, neither might be wrong. 

That said, "I am expert in speaking English" tends towards "I am a student of the way other people speak…" while "…at speaking English…" tends towards "…using English myself".